# How to skip unwanted properties when using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, properties

I am using reflection to get all the properties from class like this:

```
var props = item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance); // todo: cache & filter not-needed props)

var itemStr = string.Join(", ", 
                     props.Select(p => p.GetValue(item, null)?.ToString())
                          .ToArray());
```

item is object type Person defined like this:

```
public sealed class Person : KnowYourCustomerBase
{
     [DataMember]
     public string Surname { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public string FirstName { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public string MiddleName { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public string Address4 { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public string NationalID { get; set; }

     [DataMember]
     public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

How can I edit line of code that's getting all the properties and return them for example all except NationalID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var toExclude = new HashSet<string>("NationalID", ...);

var props = item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).
            Where(property => !toExclude.Contains(property.Name));
```

Replace ... with the name of the other properties you want to exclude and [Enumerable.Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) will keep only those not in the collection.